# Travis terminates deploy by timeout

Tags: capistrano, travis-ci

I'm trying to setup deployment on Travis CI, but even with `travis_wait` it still fails by timeout after 20 minutes

> Timeout (20 minutes) reached. Terminating "bundle exec cap staging deploy"

My *.travis.yml* is

```
language: ruby
services:
- mongodb
- redis-server
rvm:
- 2.1.1
before_script:
- cp config/secrets.example.yml config/secrets.yml
- cd frontend && npm install -g bower && npm install && bower install
script:
- RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rake db:create
- bundle exec rake rspec-rerun:spec
before_install:
- export DISPLAY=:99.0
- sh -e /etc/init.d/xvfb start
after_success:
- openssl aes-256-cbc -k $DEPLOY_KEY -in /home/travis/build/my-build_location/config/deploy_id_rsa_enc_travis -d -a -out /home/travis/build/my-build_location/config/deploy_id_rsa
- chmod 600 /home/travis/build/my-build_location/config/deploy_id_rsa
- cd /home/travis/build/my-build_location
- "[[ $TRAVIS_BRANCH = 'development' ]] && travis_wait bundle exec cap staging deploy"
env:
  global:
    secure: secret_key
```

Comment: Why is it taking that long? Can you share the logs with us?